# How to grab the MathQuill data once user types it in?

Tags: javascript, html, mathquill

I am trying to set up a chat that can parse math text, and I think MathQuill does the visuals, but I need to parse what the user types in once they submit it.

I am using the MathQuill editor:

```
<p><span id="mathTextBox" class="mathquill-editor">\sqrt[3]{8}=\frac{\sqrt{16}}{2}</span></p>
```

shown here:

http://jenseng.github.io/mathquill/demo.html

And I want to grab "\sqrt[3]{8}=\frac{\sqrt{16}}{2}" to parse. I tried

```
document.getElementById("mathTextBox").innerText
```

but it includes the toolbar text so I get:

"+Basic
πGreek
⊕Operators
≤Relationships
⇔Arrows
{Delimiters
∞Misc
∧
∨
∪
∩
◇
△
⊖
⊎
⊗
⊕
▽
⊓
⊲
⊔
⊳
⊙
◯
†
‡
≀
∐
3√8=
√16
2 "

Also, I would rather not deal with symbols (ie √) so I want it in the text format (ie \sqrt). The text is also missing a division sign after the sqrt(16).

Any ideas are greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: @maioman I get undefined

Comment: In the example #mathTextBox contains multiple childnodes styled through css and that's the way it renders math characters, you need to look for latex source ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They told me in mathquill chat (http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=mathquill) it is:

```
$(document.getElementById("mathTextBox")).mathquill('latex')
```

Comment: Did it work? In fact, it depends on MathQuill version. In 0.10 there's another way to do this.

Comment: Yes, but im curious to your other way

Comment: In v0.10.0 the syntax changed, it'd be `MQ(document.getElementById('mathTextBox')).latex()`, but the jenseng fork you're using is based on v0.9.0 which uses the API you describe.

Comment: I think you have to accept your answer so that the question in any question list is shown as answered